# Has this partial result about Legendre's Conjecture been proved?

Tags: prime-numbers, conjectures

I'd like to know if it has been proved this "partial result" about the Legendre's Conjecture:

**(1)** There are infinitely many $n$ such that there's a prime in $(n^2, (n+1)^2)$

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Since a prime number is never a square the set of all prime numbers is contained in $\cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}} (n^2, (n+1)^2)$, which are all integers but the squares. Since there are infinitely many primes while each finite collection of such intervalls is finite the results follows.

Comment: Yes, that's a dumb question, thanks for answering :P